# Get average number during period

Tags: database, average

I have a database that stores data from the stock market.

There is a table with 3 columns: *stockId*, *date*, and *volume*

New data will be inserted into the table every trading day.

How can I get a result like 'Average volume for each stock over the last 10 trading days'?

Comment: by writing a query :)

Comment: or grab results between time period and use whatever prog lang you are using to sum and divide by quantity.

Comment: i am wonder can it be done with a single query  ?

Comment: @TheoYmca sure you can

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(volume)/10 FROM table_name
Where date Between Cast('7/18/13 12:01:01' As DateTime) And Cast('7/08/13 12:01:01' as DateTime)
```

Comment: sorry... i mean a list of stock with its Average volume,
not the Average volume of whole stock market.

Comment: You have an error syntax, please remove the semicolon at the end of first line

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT AVG(volume) FROM mytable WHERE date >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

**EDIT:**

Last 10 day groups, and their averages.

```
SELECT AVG(volume) FROM mytable GROUP BY date ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: that will return the last 10 days, not last 10 trading days. Do i have to create a table to record the trading day ?

Comment: may be "group by date" can help ?

Comment: I've edited answer. And if you want to get stockId values, i think GROUP_CONCAT can be used.

Comment: the result will show up AVG(volume) of whole market in each day.

btw, that will still return the last 10 days

Comment: `SELECT AVG(volume) FROM mytable GROUP BY date ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10` Did you try this?

Comment: date field is representing trading day, isn't it? Then this query should select last 10 'date' (so trading day). What is the point that i misunderstood?

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c8dbb/4

```
CREATE TABLE Stocks
    ([StockId] int, [Date] DateTime, [Volume] int)
;

INSERT INTO Stocks
    ([StockId], [Date], [Volume])
VALUES
    (1, GetDate(), 1000),
    (1, GetDate()+1, 2000),
    (1, GetDate()+2, 4000),
    (2, GetDate(), 1000),
    (2, GetDate()+1, 1000),
    (2, GetDate()+2, 500)
;

Select StockId, AVG(Volume) [AverageVolume]
FROM Stocks
WHERE [Date] >= DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GetDate())) - 10
Group by StockId
Order by StockId
```

Comment: GetDate() may need to be changed depending on your requirements to only return the date part and a midnight time part.  I will change the code in a minute to reflect that.

Comment: it is returning the days, not trading days.

Answer (score 1):

I'm basing this off of Dodecapus answer and based off of comments you've given to other answers. I'm just including query in answer but check out sqlfiddle for working example with data.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/91599/2

```
SELECT 
    StockId
   ,AVG(Volume) [AverageVolume]
FROM Stocks
WHERE [Date] IN 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 [Date] FROM Stocks ORDER BY [Date] DESC
)
GROUP BY StockId
ORDER BY StockId
```

This will only work if there is a record of at least one stock with volume per trading day.

Comment: Excellent Explanation, and you looks handsome !

Comment: Thanks! If my answer and handsome good looks is a solution to your question then feel free to show your appreciation by accepting it :)

Answer (score 0):

Fun little query to write. Here it is:

```
SELECT AVG(x.Volume) FROM (SELECT Volume FROM StockTable WHERE Date BETWEEN
DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -10 DAY) AND NOW())x
```

This is what I used to build a sample table to work off of in `SQLFiddle`:

```
CREATE TABLE StockTable (ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, Date DATETIME, Volume INT);
INSERT INTO StockTable (Date, Volume) VALUES (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 DAY), 1000), (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), 5000),
(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 0 DAY), 3000), (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -11 DAY), 6000), (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -5 DAY), 4000), (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY), 9000);
```

<del>Here is a link to the SQLFiddle of the query in action.</del>

**Idea behind the query:** I create a **derived table** `x` which contains just the volumes within the past 10 days. Then I calculate the average of the volumes contained in that table. Voilà!

**EDIT:**

I realized specifically what you are looking for after reading through the other answers and comments. You are looking to get the average **for each** stock in the stock market over the last 10 days.

I built the sample table off of this:

```
CREATE TABLE StockTable (StockId INT NOT NULL, Date DATETIME, Volume INT);
INSERT INTO StockTable (StockId, Date, Volume) VALUES (1, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 6
DAY), 1000), (2, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), 5000),
(2, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 0 DAY), 3000), (3, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -8 DAY), 
6000), (1, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -5 DAY), 4000), 
(2, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY), 9000);
```

And the query to get your results are:

```
SELECT StockId, AVG(Volume) FROM StockTable WHERE Date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), 
INTERVAL -10 DAY) AND NOW() GROUP BY StockId
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f40f1/1) is a link to the SQLFiddle of the query in action.